# How can I add a random catergory to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure this out. I am doing some testing and trying to add random categories into a dataframe for testing but when I do it, it adds it for the all rows instead of randomly distributing it.

Here's my code:

```
import random
catergory = ['dog', 'cat', 'monkey']
df['animal'] = random.choice(catergory)
df['animal'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
monkey
monkey    124705
Name: animal, dtype: int64
```

I understand what it's doing(generating random call once and applying it to the entire DF) but how can I get it to generate the random value for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) along with `size` equal to length of dataframe to generate a random sample of given size:

```
df['animal'] = np.random.choice(catergory, size=len(df))
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)})
catergory = ['dog', 'cat', 'monkey']

df['animal'] = np.random.choice(catergory, size=len(df))
df['animal'].value_counts()
```

Result:

```
monkey    5
cat       4
dog       1
Name: animal, dtype: int64
```